# Xcode command line install to device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I am trying to install an app from XCode onto my device from the command line.   I have tried several of the "xcodebuild" command line options which do build, clean, install, etc fine. I have also searched for various solutions.

I was able to execute this command but it just builds to a folder.

> xcodebuild install -scheme "My App" -destination 'platform=iOS,id=*mydeviceid*'

I am able to take that folder from my hard drive and sync to the physical device using iTunes so all the build steps are being completed successfully.  However, it does not "run" on the device like when  Build and Run are executed in XCode.

There are some 3rd party solutions but I can't believe there isn't some native xcodebuild switch to do that.  Does anyone have suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Any success? If so, it would be great if you could post an answer.

Comment: No. I've been using a (weak) workaround.  Send the run keystrokes to XCode using AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native xcodebuild switch to install to a device.

You need to fallback to third-party options:

- `$ brew install ideviceinstaller`
- [ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy)

You can try to use Apple Configurator 2 (available in the App Store) and install the `cfgutil` command line tool.

[image: How to Install].

Ignore the fact that ^ says "Uninstall Automation Tools...", if you haven't installed already, it will say "Install Automation Tools...".